# serialization and deserialization of session data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, serialization, deserialization

I have stored session data in SQL server mode using asp.net.The data thus stored is serialized by asp.net.I am using a function to deserialize the data and return it in an object type.Now how will I retrieve the data?
I had created a class,a serializable one,using which i am storing session data in the table.

Any help regarding this will be very helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to manually deserialize objects stored in ASP.NET session state. If you have session state configured like this:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="..." />
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

ASP.NET will automaticaly serialize and deserialize it for you.
So in order to retrieve the data just read it from the session object:

```
Session["MyKey"] = new MyClass();
var myData = (MyClass)Session["MyKey"];
```

Comment: I am retrieving the sessionitemshort column.Then i am putting it into datareader to read it.Then what shall i do??Please help.Thanks

Comment: Normally you should not read data from this database manually. So why are you going to do this? What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: i am storing trying to retrieve data from the column using sessionid. so i am writing an sql query that retrieves the column.

Comment: i have this weather app which store session info like username country and city,when the same user comes back again it automatically shows the weather of the city he searched for earlier.i hav a table mapping username to session id.i am using this to find the earlier session id of the user.using the session id should be able to find out the name of the city he searched for earlier.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use session to keep imformation that will be required when user comes back later. ASP.NET sessions expire after some timeout and there is no guarantee that session data will remain in database when it is expired. Instead I suggest creating your own SQL table and using it to keep required data for each user.

Comment: I understand but i can see the data when i print the column in string format...only that i cannot fetch it in proper way..    ????objsessiondata?????GApp_Web_30fu3rhd, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullweatherpage+sessiondatak__BackingFieldk__BackingFieldk__BackingFieldxyz12345GBLondon?

Comment: it has username country and city